# Request : HTML autofill values based on user selection from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

Google sheet has fields: Customer Name, Mobile, Email, Birthday, and anniversary

For Example Google Sheet has data like below :
name: prasad,
mobile 9999999,
Email xxx@gmial.com
Birthday:11/1/1990
Birthday:11/1/2020

In HTML: Customer name is dropdown, values will come from google sheet

I need if Customer name selected from dropdown rest all fields will fill based on the selection from google sheet

For example: if I select name prasad rest will fill as per google sheet in the above example

```
HTML Code :

<h3>Customer Details</h3>

   
 
      <label>Customer Name: : <br>
      <input list="Customer_Name"  name="Customer_Name" ></label>
      <datalist id="Customer_Name" >
      <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
        <?!= getVendors(); ?>
      </datalist></td> 

    
    Customer Mobie Number:<br>
    <input type="number" name="Customer_Mobie_Number">
    <br>
    
    Customer Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="Customer_Email">
    <br>
    
   Birthday Date:<br>
    <input type="date" name="Birthday">
    <br>


JS:

    function getVendors() {
      var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sheet = active.getSheetByName("Cus_Details");
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow); 
      var data    = myRange.getValues();
      var optionsHTML = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
        optionsHTML += '<option>' + data[i][0] + '</option>';
      };
      return optionsHTML;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the dropdown list of "Customer_Name" is changed, you want to retrieve the values from the row and put to each input tag of `Mobile,Email,Birthday,anniversary`.
- Your Spreadsheet has the header of `Customer Name,Mobile,Email,Birthday,anniversary`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<h3>Customer Details</h3>
<label>Customer Name: : <br>
  <input list="Customer_Name" id="list" name="Customer_Name"></label>
<datalist id="Customer_Name">
  <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
  <?!= getVendors(); ?>
</datalist></td>
Customer Mobie Number:<br>
<input type="number" id="Customer_Mobie_Number" name="Customer_Mobie_Number">
<br>
Customer Email:<br>
<input type="email" id="Customer_Email" name="Customer_Email">
<br>
Birthday Date:<br>
<input type="date" id="Birthday" name="Birthday">
<br>
Anniversary Date:<br>
<input type="date" id="Anniversary" name="Anniversary">
<br>
<script>
  document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("change", setValues);

  function setValues(e) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([b, c, d, e]) => {
      document.getElementById("Customer_Mobie_Number").value = b;
      document.getElementById("Customer_Email").value = c;
      document.getElementById("Birthday").value = d;
      document.getElementById("Anniversary").value = e;
    }).getValues(e.target.value);
  }
</script>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function getValues(e) {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("Cus_Details");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow).createTextFinder(e).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  return range.offset(0, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(e => e instanceof Date ? e.toISOString().split("T")[0] : e);
}
```

#### Note:

- When I saw your HTML and your sample image, it seems that "Anniversary Date" and the tags below "Anniversary Date". So in this answer, I added an input tag for "Anniversary Date". This modification is a sample modified script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

### Added:

About the following your replying,

> thanks for your time, it works as I requested but when DOB or Aniversary copying from google sheet to field it is tacking one day less (Ex:14/08/1990 in sheet, in input it s coming 13/08/1990)

In this case, how about modifying above script of `getValues(e)` as follows.

#### From:

```
return range.offset(0, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(e => e instanceof Date ? e.toISOString().split("T")[0] : e);
```

#### To:

```
return range.offset(0, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(e => e instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(e, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd") : e);
```

or

```
return range.offset(0, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(e => e instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(e, active.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd") : e);
```

Comment: thanks for your time, it works as I requested but when DOB or Aniversary copying from google sheet to field  it is tacking one day less (Ex:14/08/1990 in sheet, in input it s coming 13/08/1990)

Comment: @Durga Prasad Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, I think the reason of the issue might be due to the timezone of Spreadsheet and Google Apps Script. For this, I added the modification point of my proposed script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Syntax error: Syntax error. line: 31 file: Upload file  , ( line 31 code   :   return range.offset(0, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(e => e instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(e, active.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd") : e);     )     in script i disable Chrome V8 runtime that is the problem i think , is there any way to run code without enable V8 (i cant enable why because im uploading images from html form to drive if im enable v8 images uploading error files   so...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `in script i disable Chrome V8 runtime`, in that case, how about modifying it to `return range.offset(0, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(function(e) {return e instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(e, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd") : e});` or `return range.offset(0, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(function(e) {return e instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(e, active.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd") : e});`? If this was not the result you expect, I apologize gain.